# How to programmatically list out JSON data into tableview with searching option?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I need to get programmatically `" Object A , B , C , ....."` values from below `JSON` response and list out into the tableview with searching option. Please help me. Below my JSON response out put.

```
Tableview list out style :   cell.textLabel.text = A , B , C ,.... subtitle listing relevant name values.


RESPONSE:(
        {
        A =   (
                {

                "Name" = "Nansi";
                 type =                 (
                    4
                );
                },
                  {
                "Name" = "Jani";
                 type =                 (
                    0
                );
            },
        );


        B =    (
                  {
                "Name" = "Kanuj";
                 type =                 (
                    4
                );
            }
        );

    }
)
```

Comment: do you need to show only name's value inside table or both i.e name and type

Comment: Thank you for quick replay. I need to show both...

Comment: I need to show inside table. Title : A , SubTitle : name with type.Searching option i need important. I have tried already by using below. but in tableview datasource I cant add array valuesNSArray *responsData = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"response"];
    NSDictionary *d1 = responsData.firstObject;
    NSEnumerator *enum1 = d1.keyEnumerator;
    NSArray *firstObject = [enum1 allObjects];

RESPONSE : 

[ A , B , C , D]


I tried below :

 [dataSource addObject: firstObject];

Comment: 1. And what are you searching for. `Name`, I presume? 2. And when you show `A`, the `detailTextLabel` would show both `Nansi` and `Jani`? Or just the the matched search criteria. 3. What have you tried thus far? 4. I assume the "search" will be a local filtering of the array (not another request).

Comment: I need to list out A, B , C ,... objects in the tableview title. then subtitle want to show related first index names. I need to search by using A, B , C title....

Comment: Are you open to different JSON structure? Also, can you give us examples of what A, B, and C are?

Answer (score 0):

First create model class like

```
 class student
 {
     NSstring *name;
     NSstring *type;
 }
```

parse your Json and create object of this class and add into array.

For table datasource use this array data.

if you need exact code let me know.

Comment: don't forget to accept answer, if this was your answer.

Comment: Please help me..I need sample or exact code for model class because I am a new one in this type of app processing.

Comment: your json data is invalid please check json validation online then post your json data.